# A set with a topology and a partial ordering question?

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, lattice-orders, order-topology

Suppose I have a topological space whose underlying set $X$ has a partial ordering on it. A prior this partial ordering has no relation to the topology.

Now, take any [meet semi-lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilattice) $I \subseteq X,$ and an arbitrary set of open sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ satisfying $i\in A_i$ for all $i\in I.$

> What are the conditions (on the topology or the partial ordering) that guarantee the existence of another family of open sets $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ satisfying $i\in B_i\subseteq A_i$ and $$B_i\cap B_j\subseteq B_{i\wedge j}$$ for all $i\in I$ ?

Comment: Do the $A_i$-s have any further conditions on them? Are they just open?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur: They are just open.

Comment: You also want some conditions on $\{ B_i \}$, right? Otherwise $B_i\equiv \emptyset$ always works.

Comment: Crossposted to MathOverflow: [When is this topology compatible with the partial ordering?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/441891)